# Deriving reduction formulae when two variables are involved in integration

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the correct way to derive reduction formulae for integrals which involve two variables, like:

[image]

[image]

I found these examples on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae).

For single variables, it is easy to obtain the reduction formula by applying integration by parts on that part of the functions which involves $n$. But for two variables $m,n$ how to proceed?

Comment: I think you want $m,n$, not $n,m$, on the left sides of the reduction formulas.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Didn't understand what you meant. I am looking for a way to derive those two reduction formulae on wikipedia .

Comment: I mean, the reduction formulas should say $a^2 I_{m,n} = \ldots$, not $a^2 I_{n,m} = \ldots$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, okay I see. Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These particular reduction formulas come from the fact that
$$ {\frac {{a}^{2}}{{x}^{m} \left(x^2 -{a}^{2} \right) ^{n}}}={
\frac {1}{{x}^{m-2} \left( x^2-{a}^{2} \right) ^{n}}}-{\frac {1}{
{x}^{m} \left( x^2-{a}^{2} \right) ^{n-1}}}
$$
as you see from putting everything over a common denominator...